# WooCommerce 2.6.1 Error: 'Call to undefined method WC_Shipping_Zone::get_zone_id()'

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How can i fix this bug: 'Call to undefined method WC_Shipping_Zone::get_zone_id() in .../wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-shipping-zones.php on line 32'?
It's occurred after update woocommerce to version 2.6.1

Comment: Try to contact WooCommerce, maybe they can help with your specific problem

Comment: any update on a fix for this? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @mozgras I have closed the project because of this issue